# The change of the average according to the last row in Excel ,

Tags: java, excel, postgresql, apache-poi

I want to add SQL Query result to the created Excel File. And as a result, I need to average some columns at the bottom. My question is;
The number of rows is changing in some queries. How can I shift the average result by the last row according to the changing row?

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0legd.png)

[after writing to excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/noqyJ.png)

I'm learning now to add results using Postgresql to an Excel file created using apache poi.

```
Resource resource = resourceLoader.getResource("classpath:/temps/" + querySelected.getTemplateName());

workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(resource.getInputStream());
XSSFSheet sheetTable1 = workbook.getSheet("Table1");

int rowCounter = 1;


for (tname:tname) {

    Row values = sheetTable1.createRow(rowCounter);
    rowCounter++;}


    cell = values.createCell(0, CellType.NUMERIC);
    cell.setCellValue(knz.gettablename().doubleValue());}
```

Comment: Just use a while loop until you reach the last row, then add 1 to the count and create a new row/cell to insert your value? Please show how you are attempting to access the excel data currently, and what you have tried to get the last row

Comment: If this is truly an output from an RDBMS, they almost all have an `AVERAGE` or `AVG` function which will do this for you, without any need to calculate the number of rows yourself. Excel also has one.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to improve your question.